# How to find all regex matches with match-all parts?

Tags: ruby, regex

This is my text:

```
hello foo-1 hello bar $4 hello ...
```

I need to find everything that matches `/hello .*/`:

```
["hello foo-1", "hello bar $4", ...]
```

What is the regular expression to feed to `scan()` in order to achieve this?

Comment: `hello\s+.*?(?=hello |$)` https://regex101.com/r/OCbf83/1

Comment: @AvinashRaj, please make that an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `split` with a lookahead based regex:

```
'hello foo-1 hello bar $4 hello'.split(/(?=hello)/)
```

The `(?=hello)` positive lookahead will split the string at the positions in front of each `hello` in the string.

If you need to get rid of trailing whitespace (if any) add `\s*` at the pattern start:

```
.split(/\s*(?=hello)/)
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/3EtqTi1BMl) and the [online Ruby code demo](https://ideone.com/nXVEKM).

Comment: I was about to edit with a `scan` solution - [`s.scan(/hello(?:(?!hello).)*/m)`](https://ideone.com/EdxdrH), but I still believe that `split` is the right way.

Comment: This does not discriminate between "hello" and "helloween". Nor does it permit the string to begin with anything other than "hello" (e.g. "say hello..."). Aside from the example the OP was mute on that possibility, but that would not be a problem when using`scan`.

Comment: @Cary Adding a word boundary is no rocket science. The solution us flexible enough to adjust to any further requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative without regexp. It uses [`slice_before`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) :

```
"hello foo-1 hello bar $4 hello".split.slice_before("hello").map{|words| words.join(' ')}
# => ["hello foo-1", "hello bar $4", "hello"]
"hello helloween hello halloween".split.slice_before("hello").map{|words| words.join(' ')}
# => ["hello helloween", "hello halloween"]
```

Comment: My comment above applies here as well.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm not sure it does : `"hello helloween hello halloween".split.slice_before("hello").map{|words| words.join(' ')}` returns `["hello helloween", "hello halloween"]`

Comment: @CarySwoveland: As for "say hello", that's a problem with any separator. You'd need to somehow escape it.

Comment: The problem occurs when the string begins, for example, "say hello...", with the proviso I mentioned elsewhere. I stand corrected on "helloween" being a problem.

Comment: "say hello" is not a problem when using `scan`with, for example, the regex suggested by @Avinash.